# How do I solve this differential equation with the initial condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

DE: $$y'\cos x+2y\sin x=0$$
IC:$$y(\pi/2)=1/2$$

Here is my work so far:

Step 1 (divide the equation by $cosx$ and arrange the terms):
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-2y\tan x$$

Step 2 (separate the variables and integrate):
$$\int\frac{dy}{-2y}=\int\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$

Step 3:
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln y=-\ln|\cos x|+C$$

Step 4 (Plugging in the Initial Condition and find C):
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{2})=-\ln|\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})|+C$$

The problem now is $\ln0$ is on the right side.
Did I solve the DE wrong?

Comment: i have the solution $$y(x)=C\cos(x)^2$$ i think it is the same

Comment: What is C in your case?

Comment: Your **IC** doesn't satisfy your **DE**

Comment: but since $$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$ your Logarithmus function is not defined

Comment: The IC is for the solution not the DE.

Comment: Not different. It must to satisfy.

Comment: The IC don't satisfy the DE, ergo, there can't be any derivable function that is solution of the DE and also that satisfices the IC

Comment: To repeat what others already mentioned, perhaps more explicitly, if indeed $$y'(x)\cos(x)+2y(x)\sin(x)=0$$ for every $x$ in an unspecified interval containing $x_0=\frac\pi2$ and if $$y(x_0)=\tfrac12$$ then $$1=y'(x_0)\cdot0+2\cdot\tfrac12\cdot1=0$$ which is absurd. Hence this differential equation has no solution such that $y(x_0)=\frac12$ (and actually, no solution such that $y(x_0)\ne0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we have:

$$\text{y}'\left(x\right)\cdot\cos\left(x\right)+2\cdot\text{y}\left(x\right)\cdot\sin\left(x\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\int\frac{\text{y}'\left(x\right)}{\text{y}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{-2\cdot\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Now, use:

- $$\int\frac{\text{y}'\left(x\right)}{\text{y}\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x=\ln\left|\text{y}\left(x\right)\right|+\text{C}_1\tag2$$
- $$\int\frac{-2\cdot\sin\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(x\right)}\space\text{d}x=
  -2\int\tan\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x=2\ln\left|\cos\left(x\right)\right|+\text{C}_2\tag3$$

So, we get that:

$$\ln\left|\text{y}\left(x\right)\right|=2\cdot\ln\left|\cos\left(x\right)\right|+\text{C}\tag4$$

When we want to solve $\text{C}$, use the initial condition $\text{y}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$, but we get:

$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0\tag5$$

And, when we know that:

$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left|\cos\left(x\right)\right|=\lim_{\text{n}\to0}\ln\text{n}\space\space\space\to\space\space\space-\infty\tag6$$

And so, we get:

$$\ln\left|\frac{1}{2}\right|=-\ln(2)\ne\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left|\cos\left(x\right)\right|=\lim_{\text{n}\to0}\ln\text{n}\space\space\space\to\space\space\space-\infty\tag7$$

Comment: So the conclusion is the two sides don't equal? Why?

Comment: That is strange. Maybe the wrong initial condition?

Comment: @user132522 because $-\ln(2)\approx-0.6931471806$ and that does not tends toward $-\infty$. So when you want to solve $\text{C}$ it will not be a 'number'! So, we can conclude that when we want to solve: $$\ln\left|\frac{1}{2}\right|=-\ln(2)=2\cdot\ln\left|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right|+\text{C}$$ there are no solutions for this equation!!! Because we will something like: $$-\ln(2)=2\cdot\left(-\infty\right)+\text{C}$$ And that is really strange (also keep in mind that $-\infty$ or $\infty$ is not defined as a number, so my notation is strange and only to let you see what happend)

Comment: @user132522 Yes, that is the only option left!!

Comment: This repeats the content of the OP and avoids the question asked.

Comment: ?? Well, yes, indeed a factual argument. You should know by now that offtopic and/or actually wrong answers are routinely accepted on the site (your own collection of answers being as good as any database of the phenomenon).